# How to calculate / create a phase shift for a signal created by joining arrays

Tags: matlab, octave

I have created a signal in octave / matlab that is half a sin wave, (variable `sin_half`) and half a square wave, (variable `square_half`) and I would like to phase shift the combined signals, (variable `comb_sig`) as it's one joined signal. How can I do this?

**My goal is to make a periodic signal out of joining the 1st half of one signal and the 2nd half of another signal and appending them together.  Then I want to phase shift that combined signal as if it was one signal.**

As you can see from the animation in *(figure 1)* what I currently have is the sinwave half of the signal is only phase shifting from the "center" and the square wave half is only phase shifting to the "center" instead of phase shifting the whole signal together, **like the example in** *(figure 2)*.  How can I phase shift the variable `comb_sig` all together as one combined signal like in *(figure 2)*?

[image: Comb signal animated not periodic]

[image: Comb signal animated periodic]

**Heres a static image of what 0 degree and 180 degree phase shift should look like.**  In my animation on `figure 1` the square wave never makes it over to the other side when the phase shift is 180 degrees how can I fix this?

[image: Static phase shift image 0 degree and 180 degree phase shift should look like]

See code below:

```
Vth = 0; % Threshold
amp = 1; % Amplitude of input/output
freq = 1; % frequency
for n=1:2:360 %phase shift
    ysin = amp*sin(freq*t+(n*pi/180)); % Entire sine wave creation
    ysquare = amp*sign(ysin - Vth); % Entire square wave creation 

    sin_half=ysin(1,1:length(ysin)/2); % 1st half of wave choosen (sine wave)
    square_half=ysquare(end-length(ysquare)/2+1:end); % 2nd half of wave choosen a (square wave)
    comb_sig=[sin_half,square_half]; % 1st half and 2nd half of waves combined together

    plot(t,comb_sig)
    axis([-.1 2.2*pi -1.5 1.5])
    pause(.01)
end
```

Does anyone know if there is a formula / equation / the steps required that will allow me to do this.  I was thinking that the variable `comb_sig` needs to be multiplied by something but I'm not sure by what.

PS: I'm using octave 4.0 which is similar to matlab

Comment: In your example (2), it seems that both signals are plotted ln the whole x span. The square wave seems fixed with the peaks at ~ x=0 , ~ x=pi and ~ x=2*pi , and only the sine wave seems shifted to the left during the process

Comment: @BillBokeey your right I'm having a hard time with this I'm going to make still shots and post those to the question

Comment: Oh actually, I think that this is a cut plan of 3d waves in the XZ plan, where the sine wave would be uniform on the ZY plane, and moving to the left of the XZ plan, and where the "square" wave would be square bumps on a plan moving along the Y direction

Comment: Plus the height gap at the discontinous points is always 1, and the overall maximum is 3, meaning the square bumps are of amplitude 1 and the sine wave is of amplitude 2

Comment: @BillBokeey I added a still image in case the animations were confusing things .. Notice how the square wave on `figure 1` never makes it to the other side when it's `180 degrees` like it's shown in the `static image`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the updated matlab code.

```
amp = 1; % Amplitude of input/output
freq = 1; % frequency
time = 1/freq; %time
t=0:0.001:(time-0.001);
tHalf=t(1:size(t,2)/2);
ysinHalf = amp*sin(2*pi*freq*(tHalf)); % First half sine wave creation
ysquareHalf = -amp*ones(1,size(ysinHalf,2)); % Last half square wave creation 
ywave=[ysinHalf ysquareHalf];
for n=0:2:360
    phaseShifted=circshift(ywave,[0 -round(n*size(ywave,2)/360)]);
    plot(t,phaseShifted);
    axis([0 time -(amp+0.5) (amp+0.5)]);
    pause(.01)
end
```